# Traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-7-x64, python-idle

I have been trying to run this python program using IDLE with Windows 7 and Python 2.7

```
myInput = input("Enter Something:")
print(myInput)
```

If i enter some integer value, it works fine. But when I enter some string I am getting following error.

> Enter Something:qwer
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\avmore\Desktop\hello.py", line 1, in 
>       myInput = input("Enter Something:")   File "", line 1, in  NameError: name 'qwer' is not defined

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

In python 2.7 use raw_input for strings. This was changed in Python 3.

Comment: Thanks. It is working now. But as far as I know python is dynamically typed language. So if I am using raw_input for reading the string doesn't it contradict the basic philosophy?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x. raw_input gets a string, input evaluates the value entered. Not related to types